# SoundCloud API order by hotness doesn't work anymore

Tags: api, soundcloud

It seems that the order attribute stopped to work on the API a couple of month ago, it was working in december as far as I can remember, but now it only sorts by created_at and not hotness anymore. So both of these calls return the same tracks in the same order:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?q=deadmau5&filter=streamable&order=hotness

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?q=deadmau5&filter=streamable&order=created_at
```

I tried it via my app and via the [console](http://developers.soundcloud.com/console) and both times I got the same results. Am I doing something completely wrong or is it just broken on SoundClouds side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoundCloud decided to shut down the ordering by hotness but I found a workaround which you can read about here: [Order by playbacks when fetching tracks from SoundCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394100/order-by-playbacks-when-fetching-tracks-from-soundcloud)

It uses an unofficial API call which SoundCloud themselves use to populate their "Explore" lists which is a catalog of popular track among different categories. It works and also comes with the side effect of giving you an even selection among different categories of music, which may be nice.

But since the API call is unofficial it can stop working at any time so you should have a backup in case it fails.