# Has order by hotness been removed from Soundclouds API

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

I've seen the ability to order by hotness in some tutorials for the SoundCloud API. Eg the following in PHP:

```
// create a client object with your app credentials
$client = new Services_Soundcloud('APP KEY');

// find all sounds of buskers licensed under 'creative commons share alike'
$tracks = $client->get('tracks', array('genre' => json_encode($tag), 'limit' => '20', 'order' => 'hotness')); // array('q' => 'dubstep'));

$tracks=json_decode($tracks);

die(var_dump($tracks));
```

However this returns a list of tracks with 0 plays and there is no mention of this sorting in SoundClouds documentation:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the order parameter has recently been removed. From the API blog on April 16th, 2013:

> Starting soon, GET requests to the /tracks endpoint will ignore the order parameter and default to ordering by creation date.
>   ...
>   In the meantime, it is still possible to approximate the result sets previously returned by specifying `order=hotness` by manually sorting the returned tracks by a combination of `favoritings_count` and `playback_count`.

http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/removing-hotness-param

Comment: It appears it's not possible to filter results by favoritings_count and playback_count. That's annoying.

Comment: You can't order by either of those values with the API though?

Comment: @Ben As indicated in the blog post, you must order by the values manually, in your application. It doesn't appear that there's any ordering functionality or filtering for those two attributes in the API at the moment. You can find the list of track options [here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks).

Comment: Therefore to get the top tracks by genre yesterday you would have to get all tracks uploaded yesterday first then sort.

Comment: What is the max limit for each API call?